# Can login over LAN with SSH - but not from local keyboard

Tags: raspbian-stretch, login

I setup a headless RPi0W, connected to it with SSH and gave it a new password using "passwd" - works great.  However, if I boot with a directly connected USB keyboard and composite video monitor, it will not accept the same password that I use to login over SSH.  Why can't user "pi" login either locally (USB keyboard) or remotely (SSH) with the same password?  Note: The OS is Stretch Light and there is only one user.

Comment: probably a keyboard mapping issue - do you have a password with non alphanumeric characters? If so, change the password to something with only a-zA-Z0-9 - login using the keyboard, then fix the keyboard mapping (you may be able to change the keyboard mapping using SSH - but, I've had issues (in the past) doing that)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Bravo, you nailed it!  I changed to all alphabetic password using SSH.  Then I logged on with a local keyboard and ran  sudo nano /etc/default/keyboard.  In nano, I changed XKBLAYOUT from "gb" to "us".  Now my original password works in both cases.